# MySQL gives error: "Query 1 ERROR: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'" on update

Tags: mysql

I am running the query:

```
UPDATE lookup 
    set label = 'ATM' 
where id in (select id 
                from lookup 
                where option_type = 'put' 
                and label = 'OTM' 
                order by strike_price desc 
                LIMIT 1
            )
```

which gives the error:

> Query 1 ERROR: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Or this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268429/1235-this-version-of-mariadb-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-sub

Comment: @NicoHaase I had made an attempt to do but could not do.